# SQL query for NOT IN operator

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need your help in writing a tricky query. The scenario is like below

[image: Table]

Location with attributes A,I,Z should be excluded(which is simple). But there is one exception. When location contains a combination of A and I attributes - it should not be excluded(i.e, Bangalore should not be excluded).
Whereas Delhi (with Attributes A and Q would be excluded). So the output of the query should be like below.

[image: Output]

The query for the exclusion is simple like below

```
SELECT LOCATION
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTRIBUTE NOT IN ('A','I','Z')
```

But it needs to be extended to consider the exception for the attributes A and I.

Comment: Include your table data and output as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to group according to the location and count the number of different attributes. By using a case statement you could match just the relevant attributes:

```
SELECT   location
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY location
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN attribute IN ('A', 'I') THEN 1 END) = 2 OR
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN attribute IN ('A', 'I', 'Z') THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query will the locations, which are not in A,I,Z , excluding Bangalore.

```
SELECT Location
FROM 
TABLE WHERE 
LOCATION NOT IN 
(SELECT LOCATION, 
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTRIBUTE IN ('A','I','Z')
UNION ALL
SELECT LOCATION
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTRIBUTE IN ('A','Q')
GROUP BY LOCATION
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ATTRIBUTE) = 2)
UNION ALL
SELECT LOCATION
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTRIBUTE IN ('A','I')
GROUP BY LOCATION
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ATTRIBUTE) = 2
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I did not see that Delhi condition. I should have done that

Comment: @Venkataraman R - No actually, third union is not required. Delhi should be excluded.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - With the first two SELECT, Delhi will not be included.

Comment: @kavanabangalore, yes but the second one is a special case that was not part of your question so I am not sure what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a third option:

```
    SELECT t.LOCATION
    FROM TABLE t
    WHERE t.ATTRIBUTE NOT IN ( 'A','I','Z' )
       OR ( t.ATTRIBUTE = 'A'
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                    FROM TABLE t2
                    WHERE t.LOCATION   = t2.LOCATION
                      AND t2.ATTRIBUTE = 'I' ) )
```